# How to include custom links in html template with letterhead

Tags: email-template, html

Currently, I'm working on CSAT survey's for the customer with a link.

So, right now I am able to include anchor tag in HTML template without letterhead.

This is the link

```
<a href="{!$Label.Training_Site_Details}&cId={!relatedTo.contact.Id}&caId={!relatedTo.Id}">Survey Link</a>
```

But I want to achieve the same functionality with letterheads too.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: What ave you tried so far? are you using standard email, or apex email? can you add more content and context?

Comment: I have already created both HTML templates with & without letterheads.I'm not able to use the above link with letterheads Because it's showing as plain text  @PranayJaiswal

Answer (score -1):

You can do the same by using HTML editor. By using the insert link option available at the top of editor you can achieve.